# How to find minimums of array ( local minimums graphic)

Tags: php, math, graphics

i need to find minimums of graphic.

Code :

```
$mindots = array();

for ($i = 0; $i<=sizeof($chart); $i++  ) {
    if ( $chart[$i] >=0  ) { 
        $mindots[1] = $i;
        if ($chart[$i+1] >= $chart[$i] && $chart[$i+2] >= $chart[$i] ) {
            break;
        }
    }   
}

for ($i = $mindots[1]+2; $i<=sizeof($chart); $i++  ) {
    if ( $chart[$i] >=0  ) { 
        $mindots[2] = $i;
        if ($chart[$i+1] >= $chart[$i] && $chart[$i+2] >= $chart[$i]) {
            break;
        }
    }   
}

for ($i = $mindots[2]+2; $i<=sizeof($chart); $i++  ) {
    if ( $chart[$i] >=0 ) { 
        $mindots[3] = $i;
        if ($chart[$i+1] >= $chart[$i] && $chart[$i+2] >= $chart[$i] ) {
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Here you can see graphics : 
[image]

as result i have :

```
array(3) { [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(6) [3]=> int(8) }
```

but i need numbers like ~ 6 22 36 .

My graph size ( x coord max ) in range 35-45 numbs.

My values :

```
0.0;2.0
1.0;4.0
2.0;16.0
3.0;18.0
4.0;7.0
5.0;4.0
6.0;2.0
7.0;2.0
8.0;5.0
9.0;7.0
10.0;10.0
11.0;10.0
12.0;12.0
13.0;7.0
14.0;5.0
15.0;9.0
16.0;10.0
17.0;11.0
18.0;12.0
19.0;6.0
20.0;2.0
21.0;0.0
22.0;2.0
23.0;6.0
24.0;11.0
25.0;11.0
26.0;12.0
27.0;11.0
28.0;6.0
29.0;7.0
30.0;11.0
31.0;10.0
32.0;11.0
33.0;10.0
34.0;2.0
35.0;0.0
36.0;0.0
37.0;2.0
38.0;4.0
39.0;14.0
40.0;15.0
41.0;7.0
42.0;4.0
```

Or in array form ( print )

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 16 [3] => 18 [4] => 7 [5] => 4 [6] => 2 [7] => 2 [8] => 5 [9] => 7 [10] => 10 [11] => 10 [12] => 12 [13] => 7 [14] => 5 [15] => 9 [16] => 10 [17] => 11 [18] => 12 [19] => 6 [20] => 2 [21] => 0 [22] => 2 [23] => 6 [24] => 11 [25] => 11 [26] => 12 [27] => 11 [28] => 6 [29] => 7 [30] => 11 [31] => 10 [32] => 11 [33] => 10 [34] => 2 [35] => 0 [36] => 0 [37] => 2 [38] => 4 [39] => 14 [40] => 15 [41] => 7 [42] => 4 )
```

If someone dont understand graph , i made another  (with another values )

[image]

How can i do it?

Comment: Can you show the output of `print_r($minidots);`

Comment: many problems. you have a messy code, lots of repetitions, because you have a separate loop for each minimum. but how could you know beforehand how many minimums are there? there are other problems like how do you know that indexes +1 and +2 exist? what if you're checking the last element? also, I don't understand why you check at +2... `$i<=sizeof($chart)` - this is incorrect to, should be `<`.

Comment: yes, added. sizeof my grapf (max x ) is in range 35 - 45

I dont know PHP well, only delphi. Its easier for me to white smth like this. But, i found points more than 0 and where graph increases .You can see values ...

Comment: well, first of all, update the question with a proper description of the task. you've already confused one answerer.

Comment: sorry about size .. my fail .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understand your question right, then next code might help you:

```
$localMinimums = array ();

for ($i = 1; $i<count($chart)-1; $i++) {
    if ($chart[$i-1] > $chart[$i] && $chart[$i+1] >= $chart[$i]) {
        $localMinimums[$i] = $chart[$i];
    }   
}

asort($localMinimums);
$result = array_slice($localMinimums, 0, 3); //I think that you need only 3 minimum elements
```

Or maybe you need slice by thresold?

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array:

```
// Sorts by value.. 
asort($chart);
```

then just get min:

```
// Smallest
$smallest = $chart[0];
```

Comment: What if there are multiples with the same value?

Comment: You can see , that in 35 and 36 the same values , but i need to find only one 1 value in this area ( minimum).

Comment: Then you can use array_unique to remove multiple values. – Hardy 40 secs ago

No. Becouse i can have 0 in x : 30 and 0 in x : 45 . I cant ignore it

Comment: Ok, not understading this anymore.. question is "how can i find minimum of array" i answered.. that's it..

Comment: it's mainly the OP's fault. but you see, there were some signs, in the text it is in plural, and the result contains several numbers...